# how to aggregate a linq query by different groupings

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

How do you perform multiple seperate aggregations on different grouping in linq?

for example, i have a table:

```
UNO     YOS Ranking Score
123456  1   42       17
645123  3   84       20
```

I want to perform an set of aggregations on this data both grouped and ungrouped, like:

```
var grouped = table.GroupBy(x => x.score )
                    .Select(x => new 
                    {
                        Score = x.Key.ToString(),
                        OverallAverageRank = x.Average(y => y.Ranking),
                        Year1RankAvg = x.Where(y => y.YOS == 1).Average(y => y.Ranking),
                        Year2RankAvg = x.Where(y => y.YOS == 2).Average(y => y.Ranking)
                        //...etc
                    });
```

I also want to perform different aggregations (standard deviation) on the same slices and whole-set data.

I can't figure out how to both group and not group the YOS at the same time and while this compiles fine, when it comes to runtime, I get "Sequence contains no elements", if any of the YOS averages are in.

Comment: What is `score` and where is it in your table?

Comment: @NetMage Darn, forgot to paste that column into the post. Ill edit it on now, its the numeric field im grouping on

Answer (score 0):

Like anything programming, when you have a sequence of similar items, use a collection. In this case, I left it `IEnumerable`, but you could make it a `List`, or a `Dictionary` by `YOS`, if desired.

```
var ans = table.GroupBy(t => t.Score)
               .Select(tg => new {
                    Score = tg.Key,
                   OverallAverageRank = tg.Average(t => t.Ranking),
                   YearRankAvgs = tg.GroupBy(t => t.YOS).Select(tyg => new { YOS = tyg.Key, RankAvg = tyg.Average(t => t.Ranking) })
               });
```

If you need the range of years from 1 to max (or some other number) filled in, you can modify the answer:

```
var ans2 = ans.Select(soryr => new {
                    soryr.Score,
                    soryr.OverallAverageRank,
                    YearRankDict = soryr.YearRankAvgs.ToDictionary(yr => yr.YOS),
                    YearMax = soryr.YearRankAvgs.Max(yr => yr.YOS)
              })
              .Select(soryr => new {
                  Score = soryr.Score,
                  OverAverageRank = soryr.OverallAverageRank,
                  YearRankAvgs = Enumerable.Range(1, soryr.YearMax).Select(yos => soryr.YearRankDict.ContainsKey(yos) ? soryr.YearRankDict[yos] : new { YOS = yos, RankAvg = 0.0 }).ToList()
              });
```

If you preferred, you could modify the original `ans` to return `RankAvg` as `double?` and put `null` in place of `0.0` when adding missing years.